# Git workflow to create a new branch with uncomitted changes

Tags: git

I am wondering what my best options are in this situation I am often in. Basically my team is very slow to approve PRs and my next task is building upon the previous.

So I have `Branch A` which is feature complete but sitting in a PR for a long time. I'd like to build upon it with `Branch B` which completely relies on non-merged changes from `Branch A`. What is my best workflow here?

In my current situation I actually have done all my changes for `Branch B` but they are sitting as uncommitted files on `Branch A`. Do I just `git stash` and `git checkout -b BranchB` and `git stash apply`? Will this include all my changes from `Branch A` (which should mean I won't face conflicts?)

If you are wondering why I don't just try and find out, I am very scared of what might happen.

Comment: You can do `git checkout -b new-branch-name`, it won't change anything, your uncommitted files are still there. You can then add and commit your files on this new branch

Comment: Also, make sure you understand what you're doing here. If you then try to merge this new branch into your main branch, before branch A's code review has been completed and branch A has been merged, you will in fact drag along all changes on A as well.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This I understand (your second point) and what you say is what I was hoping to be true. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your repository and working folder is in this state:

- You have Branch A checked out
- You have made modifications to files in Branch A
- You do not yet have Branch B

Then you can simply do this:

```
git checkout -b Branch-B
```

This will create and check out Branch B, "on top" of Branch A. Your uncommitted files are still present and still uncommitted, basically, your working folder is left unchanged. You can then start adding and committing those files to your hearts content.

---

Though you said in the comments that you understand what you're doing in regards to the following remarks, I'm just going to put a caveat here for future visitors as well.

If Branch A is not yet merged into your main branch, and you do this, create Branch B based on Branch A, if you then try to merge Branch B back into your main branch **before Branch A is merged**, you will drag along all changes in Branch A as well. Essentially you will merge Branch A's changes into the main branch, even though the branch itself is considered unmerged.

Answer (score 0):

Create yet another `Branch C` and work there as you'd like, merging in the upstream changes later

`stash`ed work can still cause conflicts and they can be more annoying to work with and are easier to accidentally lose or lose track of